# JS RegExp with StringLiteral in match() issue

Tags: javascript, regex, match

If I use this....

```
var str = 'Testing123@@';

if (str.match(/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,\-,",',.,:,=,{,},\[,\],(,)]).{8,}/)) {
  args.IsValid = true;
}
```

This works fine.

But I updated to try and use a StringLiteral for the '8' so in theory it could be dynamic.

```
var passwordMinLength = 8;


const regex = new RegExp(`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,\-,",',.,:,=,{,},\[,\],(,)]).{${passwordMinLength},}`);

if (str.match(regex)) {
  args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Though, this returns false even though in the JS debugger the string output looks the same as the previous implementation. The 8 is showing up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The two regexes are different due to string interpolation. See this comparison from my Notepad++:

[image]

You need:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~,+,\\-,",',.,:,=,{,},\\[,\\],(,)]).{${passwordMinLength},}`);
```

Comment: Yes, based on the referenced article I came to that conclusion as well. But thank you for the text output, I had assumed they looked the same but I was mistaken.

Comment: @JohnPete22 A monospaced text editor only misleads under 2 conditions: incorrect output pasting and hidden chars like zero-width space chars and control characters.